# GCP Log Metrics Explorer Issue

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-logging, google-cloud-monitoring

I have a very simple log based metric created to pull out errors. Following is JSON view of from the metrics explorer

This one created with custom metric shows me data

```
{
  "dataSets": [
    {
      "timeSeriesFilter": {
        "filter": "metric.type=\"logging.googleapis.com/log_entry_count\" resource.type=\"app_script_function\" metric.label.\"severity\"=\"ERROR\"",
        "minAlignmentPeriod": "60s",
        "aggregations": [
          {
            "perSeriesAligner": "ALIGN_RATE",
            "crossSeriesReducer": "REDUCE_NONE",
            "alignmentPeriod": "60s",
            "groupByFields": []
          },
          {
            "crossSeriesReducer": "REDUCE_NONE",
            "alignmentPeriod": "60s"
          }
        ]
      },
      "targetAxis": "Y1",
      "plotType": "LINE"
    }
  ],
  "options": {
    "mode": "COLOR"
  },
  "constantLines": [],
  "timeshiftDuration": "0s",
  "y1Axis": {
    "label": "y1Axis",
    "scale": "LINEAR"
  }
}
```

This one created with a custom metric does not show data for the same time frame

```
{
  "dataSets": [
    {
      "timeSeriesFilter": {
        "filter": "metric.type=\"logging.googleapis.com/user/TestApps2\"",
        "minAlignmentPeriod": "60s",
        "aggregations": [
          {
            "perSeriesAligner": "ALIGN_RATE",
            "crossSeriesReducer": "REDUCE_NONE",
            "alignmentPeriod": "60s",
            "groupByFields": []
          },
          {
            "crossSeriesReducer": "REDUCE_NONE",
            "alignmentPeriod": "60s"
          }
        ]
      },
      "targetAxis": "Y1",
      "plotType": "LINE"
    }
  ],
  "options": {
    "mode": "COLOR"
  },
  "constantLines": [],
  "timeshiftDuration": "0s",
  "y1Axis": {
    "label": "y1Axis",
    "scale": "LINEAR"
  }
}
```

Custom metric TestApps2 contains following additional filter:

```
severity="ERROR"
resource.type="app_script_function"
```

Note during metric creation the above does show the logs in preview logs.
I have to use the custom metric to add labels and inject those into emails.

What could be the possible reason for this failure of custom metric view?

Comment: The custom metric is pretty simple - Its counter based, uses units of 1 and filter selection as given above - severity="ERROR"
resource.type="app_script_function" .  I am trying to capture a "Error: Client ID is required." console.error output from the script in my metrics.  I haven't used Cloud reporting but I don't think that is needed for troubleshooting in this case.

Comment: Please could you share your custom metric, as well as other details that may help to troubleshoot the issue? I am unable to reproduce it. Do you know the existence of [Cloud Error Reporting](https://cloud.google.com/error-reporting/reference)? It's notifications through email may help you to simplify the setup.

Comment: DId you find a solution? I'm getting a similar error for a counter type custom log-based metric. "View logs for metric" shows logs entries, but Metrics Explorer shows "No data is available for selected timeframe" regardless of aggregator, alignment, timeframe selections.